# Set-Cookie header no longer removing cookie

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, browser

So I've been using the following code for a while now

**Set cookie**

```
res.cookie(AUTH_TOKEN_NAME, token, {
  maxAge: AUTH_TOKEN_EXP,
  domain: DOMAIN,
  signed: true,
  httpOnly: true
});
```

**Expire cookie**

```
res.clearCookie(AUTH_TOKEN_NAME);
res.redirect(303, '/');
```

And it's been working fine, however, only after just recently deploying to production this code has stopped working. Things to note:

- Code is ran from a sub domain e.g. `x.domain.com` and `DOMAIN=domain.com` (I've also tried `.domain.com` which also didn't work)
- The header *is* in the response (see below)
- I'm not explicitly setting `path` as Express assumes `/` if it's not provided - regardless, I did this to rule it out, it didn't make a difference.
- This *isn't* browser specific, I've not tried it on every browser but behaviour is the same on Chrome or Safari and...
- This *does work* locally i.e. being run from `localhost:3000` with `DOMAIN=localhost`

I don't think this is an Express problem as it seems to be doing it's job, it *seems* like the problem lies with the browser but the fact it works locally contradicts that so I've came to the conclusion it is something to do with Express.

Redeployed `node_modules`, double checked versions etc. (I use a lock file anyway) and can't quite put my finger on what's going on.

**HTTP Request**

```
GET /logout HTTP/1.1
Host: x.domain.com
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://x.domain.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,da;q=0.7
Cookie: auth_token=xxxxxx
```

**HTTP Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Content-Length: 50
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /
Vary: Accept
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Set-Cookie: auth_token=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
X-Powered-By: Express
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 25 Feb 2018 13:24:01 GMT
```

**Versions**

- Node: **8.1.4**
- Express: **4.16.2**

Answer (score 1):

The [express docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie) state, "Web browsers and other compliant clients will only clear the cookie if the given options is identical to those given to res.cookie(), excluding expires and maxAge."

Therefore I would suggest you try:

```
res.clearCookie(AUTH_TOKEN_NAME, {
  domain: DOMAIN,
  signed: true,
  httpOnly: true
});
```

Comment: I see your logic, but if that were the case I wouldn't expect it to work locally either. Nevertheless, I'll give it a go :)

Comment: For me, adding `domain` and `secure` did the trick - these are not populated in my local set-up... Source documentation on this would be appreciated!